# Intermittent timeout on Kubernetes services

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I was wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction as I've been pulling my hair out with this one.

So, I've got a couple of simple services running (through a NodePort) and for the most of time, they run fine.
But every once in a while, we get a timeout on the services which I cannot explain.

I've been testing with the following commandline which will reproduce the issue quite fast.

`while true; do clear &&  wget k8s-mn01:30088/CallBack/Status -O /dev/null && sleep 0.05; done`

Once the issue presents itself, I will get the following response:

```
Resolving k8s-mn01 (k8s-mn01)... 192.168.123.101
Connecting to k8s-mn01 (k8s-mn01)|192.168.123.101|:30088... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

I'm currently running a 3-node BareMetal cluster consisting of 1 master and 2 workers.
Everything is installed on CentOS 7.

Kubernetes version 1.17 is installed with the flannel network.

At first (based on the information on the internet) I thought that this might be related to dropped packets which I would see in `conntrack`. But unfortunately, this is not the case.

One final thing which might be of interrest: When I try to access the service on the master node, it will always fail.

Can anyone give me pointers in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could You please check if your cluster is healty? Use `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`. Could you show logs of those services with `kubectl logs <name_of_pod>` so we could see why they're going down? Can You make a test for me and make 2 pods, 1 in worker1, 1 in worker2, and curl from worker1 to worker2?

Comment: Hi jt97,
I executed the task ```kubectl get pods --all-namespaces``` in which I can see the application running without any restarts. When I dive into the logs, it does not show anything in regards of the pod going down... it keeps running. For the last test I will do this today and let you know.